# Получить данные с сервера с авторизацией

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, get

Друзья, есть сервер, есть GET запрос вида example.ru/get.

Каким образом вставить в заголовок запроса имя пользователя и пароль? На obj-c, конечно же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того как именно оно передается, насколько понимаю, в гет запросе логин пароль можно засунуть либо прямо в URl (example.ru/get?login=aaaa&pass=bbb), тогда надо собрать их в строке с помощью `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.ru/get?login=%@&pass=%@", login, pass];`, либо же они могут быть запрятаны в хедер, тогда нужно копать в сторону метода `- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field` класса NSMutableURLRequest . Что конкретно использовать зависит от сервера

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!